# In-order Binary Tree Iterator Python

Tags: python

I currently have a BinaryTree class that looks like so:

```
class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
    ...other methods...
    def __iter__(self):
        return BinaryTreeIter(self)
```

the root of the BinaryTree is of a class Node, that looks like so:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,key,value):
        self.right = None
        self.left = None
        self.value = value
        self.key = key
```

Finally, my BinaryTreeIter looks like this:

```
class BinaryTreeIter:
    def __init__(self, tree):
        self.tree = tree
        self.res = None

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

def in_order(self, root):
    if not root:
        return
    if root.left:
        for x in self.in_order(root.left):
            yield x
    yield (root)
    if root.right:
        for x in self.in_order(root.right):
            yield x

    def __next__(self):
        if self.res is None:
            self.res = self.in_order(self.tree.root)
        for node in self.res:
            return node
        raise StopIteration
```

Is there a better of way of implementing the **next** method? Aside, from maybe have the self.res = self.in_order in the **init** method.

Comment: The easy way, which you should probably do in practice, is to just make a recursive generator almost identical to your existing `in_order` function, but tracking state manually the old-school way is a fun learning experience.

Comment: @user2357112 could you show an example? That's what I was trying to accomplish, but couldn't.

Comment: @lorenzocastillo Sorry, I misunderstood.

Comment: @user2357112 look at my modified question, please. I'm stumped. Thanks